# ArcGIS Field Calculator using Python Parser gives ERROR 000989

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000989

I am attempting to learn how to update a field using Python with Codeblock showing.

The script is supposed to return a value to a text field based on a numerical value in two float fields but I keep getting an error:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```py
def wType(SWPULP):

    if SWPULP>=75:
        return "SP"
    elseif HWPULP>=75:
        return "HP"
    else:
        return "MW"
```

Expression

```
STANDTYPE = wType(!SWPULP!)
```

error message:

> ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 4)

I have standard 4 space indent (solved that error previously) but now I am stuck as to why it will not work.

SCREENSHOT[image]

Comment: This is a Python syntax issue. The keyword you want is `elif`. There are actually a number of ways to format a code block in SE; I changed your single backtick to be triple-backtick. Note that best practice is to follow the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which includes four-space indenting and lower_case variable names.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning this up for me, directing me to the style guide, and pointing out my syntax issue. Now I have another issue... Error 000539: Error running expression: wType(11.989) - that's the first value looked up. It is a FLOAT field.

Comment: If you want to use HWPULP, you need to pass it in. The documentation has examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
def wType(SWPULP, HWPULP):
    if SWPULP>=75:
        return "SP"
    elif HWPULP>=75:
        return "HP"
    else:
        return "MW"
```

Call with:

```
wType(!SWPULP!, !HWPULP!)
```